# jquery rating repeating first value

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a column that contains numerical values from 1 to 5.
I want to convert this values to a star rating system and i used [THIS](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)

The problem that I have is that the plugin uses the first cell value and repeat this value on all the cells of the column for rating even if the numerical values are different: i have in the rating colum cells starting with 4, 4, 2, 3 but the plugin applies four stars ( so the first value) to all the cells in the column ( the table id is "tabel" and I applied a custom class .rating and connected the rating plugin to this class, the column is the 11-th column in the table :

```
var items = [];

$('#tabel tbody tr td:nth-child(11)').each(function() {
  items.push($(this).text());
});

var i;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  $(function() {
     $('.rating').rateYo({
      rating: items[i],
      starWidth: "20px",
      readOnly: true
    });
  });
}
```

What is wrong here???

Comment: you are using `.rating` class to apply the ratings which will target all elements with this class every time in the loop

Comment: Then how can i avoid this??? Maybe put the value in the cell inside a specific span??? use a custom attribute??? The cells have autogenerated spans like edit1_Rating, edit2_Rating, etc

Comment: cant tell with seeing the html that is related to the code you posted try adding thay part in your post

Comment: <TABLE class="table" id="tabel" cellpadding="0">
                      <TH class="trclass" data-field="Confidence">
                                  <SPAN {$ID_orderlinkattrs}>
                                      {$label public_snails Confidence}
                                    </SPAN>
                                  </TH>
                    <TR class="tryout">
                            <TD class="tryout rating">
                                  {$Confidence_value}
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
       </TABLE>

Comment: add in your originally post by editing

Answer (score 6):

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  $(function() {
     $('.rating').eq(i).rateYo({
      rating: items[i],
      starWidth: "20px",
      readOnly: true
    });
  });
}
```

Try this

Comment: .eq(i) will select element with index i .

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you! So the selection of the element with eq was the key....